# Calculate exponent when not allowed to use Math.pow?

Tags: java, pow

I need to write a method named `pow2` that accepts a real number base and an integer exponent as parameters.  It should return the base raised to the given power.  Your code should work for both positive and negative exponents.  For example, the call `pow2(2.0, -2)` returns `0.25`. Do not use Math.pow in your solution.

This is what I have so far:

```
public double pow2(double x,int y){
    double total=1;
    for(int i=1;i<=y;i++){
        total*=x;
    }
    return total;
}
```

But the problem is when I try to call `pow(2.0, -2)`, it returns me 1.0 instead. How do I implement this method?

Comment: Your code is working fine for positive exponentials.  `System.out.println(pow2(2.0,4));` gives me `16.0`

Comment: No.It dont work for negative numbers.

Comment: For instance when i call for pow2(8.0, -1),it gives me 1.0 instead of 0.125.

Comment: Isn't it obvious to you that the condition `i <= y` is **not true** for `y == -2`?

Comment: It seems pretty obvious : you're looping `for i` from 1 to `y`. So if `y == -2`, you'll never enter your for-statement and directly return `total` (which is, of course, 1).

Answer (score 3):

You have to branch, depending if you have a negative or a positive value.

Here a version that works with recursion:

```
public double pow2(double x,int y){
    return _pow2(1.0, x, y);
}

private double _pow2(double res, double x, int y) {
    if (y < 0) return _pow2(res/x, x, y+1);
    if (y > 0) return _pow2(res*x, x, y-1);
    return res;
}
```

If `y` is too big or too small, then you'll run into a stack overflow, so changing it to a non-recursive function is left to the op.

**Edit**: about your last question, you set the result to `1.0`, the body of the loop is never used because `!(1 <= -2)`, so you return the unmodified result of `1.0`

Answer (score 1):

Well, finally if you want to do it in an iterative way, just check first if `y` is positive or negative.

```
public double pow2(double x, int y)
{
    double total = 1.0;

    if(y > 0)
    {
        for(int i = 1 ; i <= y ; i++)
        {
            total *= x;
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        for(int i = -1 ; i >= y ; i--)
        {
            total /= x;
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(pow2(2,3));

}

public static double pow2(double x,int y){
    double total=1;
    for(int i=1;i<=y;i++){
        total*=x;
    }
    return total ;
}
```

Comment: No.I only need the method in this case.But if there is negative numbers,it is still wrong.

Comment: Because in your for loop your variable "i" is incerementing from 1 to y. If y is negative loop does not work. I am working on it. I will post edited solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static double pow2(double x,int y){
    double total=1;
    if(y>0){
    for(int i=1;i<=y;i++){
        total*=x;
    }
    return total;
    }
    else if (y<0){
        double temp=1/x;//this makes 2 as 1/2
        y=y*-1;         //to have a meaningful iteration if for loop
        for(int i=1;i<=y;i++){
            total*=temp;
        }   
        return total;
    }else
        return 1;
}
```